# What happened to inheritance here?

Tags: java, inheritance

Here's my code

```
class Animal{
  public int numOf=3;
}

class Dog extends Animal{
  public int numOf=4;
}
class TestCase{
  public static void main(String[] args){
      Animal a = new Dog();
      Dog d = new Dog();
      System.out.println(a.numOf);
      System.out.println(d.numOf);
  }
}
```

When I do `a.numOf` , should not it be 4, as it would be in case of a Method?

Comment: You don't override fields, just methods. In other words, you don't override state, just behaviour.

Comment: @RohitJain why fields are not overriden? or polymorphic?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Polymorphism does not apply to fields.

A field is resolved against the declared type of the variable it's accessed on.

```
System.out.println(a.numOf); // refers to A's, since a's declared type is A
System.out.println(d.numOf); // refers to D's, since d's declared type is D
```

You have a case of [`hiding`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8) here.

Comment: Sotirios, we gotta have a little talk about you beatin' me to the gun on all these java questions!

Comment: @RichardJPLeGuen LOL. Chat window is open. Go for it ;-)

Comment: @RichardJPLeGuen The beatin' will continue until I'm satisfied (and/or have something to do at work).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis why fields could not be overriden? mean why fields are not polymorphic?